# Give an example of a set with full Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ that is also a countable union of nowhere dense sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was asked to prove or give a counterexample of the statement.

Assume $P$ is a subset of $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure equal to $1$. Then $P$ is not a countable union of nowhere dense sets.

I find that there are nowhere dense sets with positive measure. So I am not able to derive this from subadditivity.

Comment: This is a classic problem.  Otherwise phrased: $[0,1]$ is the union of a meager set and a set of measure zero.  I learned this many years ago in Oxtoby's nice little book, *Measure and Category*.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a counterexample:

For any $n$, there is [a fat cantor se](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set)t $C_n$ of measure $> 1 - 1/n$. Each $C_n$ is nowhere dense, since it is closed and has empty interior.

The union $C_1 \cup C_2 \cup \ldots $ has measure one, and is a countable union of nowhere dense sets.